# Make a single object transparent in viewport shading

Tags: mesh, objects, 3d-view

I have two meshes, with one I want to use as a reference. I think it would be easier if I would be able to see through one of the meshes, but the closest I can get is x-ray mode where all of the meshes are transparent. Is there a way for only one mesh to be transparent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several different ways to make an object transparent.

First is to tell Blender to only use a wireframe to preview the object:

[image]

I've set properties/object/viewport display/display as to "wire".  Now I can see through the object.  It will still render.  If I disable overlays, it will not be displayed on the viewport at all.  I typically use this for "cage" style meshes, like mesh deformers.  To prevent these kinds of objects from being rendered, I'll usually assign them to a collection-- maybe a sub-collection-- with rendering disabled.

The next option is to set a color for that object, and use "object" coloring in the render dropdown:

[image]

I've given this object a color in the same viewport display sub-panel as before, which allows me to specify some alpha.  (I've also specified a different color.)  Now, in solid mode view only (Workbench), that object is halfway transparent.  It won't affect its display in material or render previews.

Personally, I never really use this option, but it might be the closest to what you're looking for.

We can do something similar with materials:

[image]

Here, I've specified viewport display settings for a particular material, and set the rendering dropdown to use material settings.  Again, I can specify a color and an alpha, but only the faces assigned to that material will be made transparent.  For good or ill-- good, as long as you're prepared for it-- any other objects with that same material will also be transparent.  Again, this is solid mode only.

I actually do use this option sometimes, like when I have a character combined into a single object, and there are parts of it that obscure details important to animation.  Like, an eyeshadow sphere surrounding the eyes, where I still want the animators to be able to animate in solid view and see where the eyes are actually pointing.

If we want to set transparency for material or rendered views, we can use the shader editor to do so, mixing materials into transparency BSDFs as desired.

Answer (score 2):

in object properties, choose "wire" for display as

[image]